# How to grep a log file from specific date to end of file?

Tags: grep

I am looking to grep an Apache access_log file from a specific date/time to the end of the file, so for example I want to grep from the first match of the following string to the end of the file:

```
19/Jan/2016:22:
```

What is the simplest way to do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Provided there are fewer than 999,999 lines:

```
grep -A 999999 '19/Jan/2016:22:' access_log
```

But this would be a better solution as it doesn't restrict the number of lines after the match:

```
sed -n '/19\/Jan\/2016:22:/,$p' access_log
```

Answer (score 4):

use [sed](http://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) instead:

```
sed -n '\#19/Jan/2016:22:#,${/<regexp>/p}' access.log
```

where `<regexp>` is a sub-expression you would like to find in lines after 19/Jan/2016:22: